# Cant pass variables within an extended View class -Discord.py Cogs

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

```
        embed.add_field(name="Player 1", value=new_game['player_1']['name'], inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Player 2", value=new_game['player_2']['name'], inline=True)
        await ctx.send(view=view, embed=embed)
    
        class StartMatch(View):
            def __init__(self, player_1, player_2):
                self.player_1 = player_1
                self.player_2 = player_2
                print(f'This is player 1 {self.player_1}, player 2 {self.player_2}')
```

View and embed is sending alright until I try passing 2 values through it `view = StartMatch(player_1, player_2)`.

Im not very strong at OOP so I might be missing something.

the values gets printed as intended but `await ctx.send(view=view, embed=embed)` doesnt seem to work after I do so...

I hope i managed to explain well let me know if you need further details!

edit:
I didnt manage to raise any error

fixed code:

````
def __init__(self, player_1, player_2):
        super().__init__()
        self.player_1 = player_1
        self.player_2 = player_2
        print(f'This is player 1 {self.player_1}, player 2 {self.player_2}')```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you subclass something & override the `__init__`, you should call the parent class' `__init__` method as well. Otherwise, you're not initializing the parent class.

```py
def __init__(self, ...):
    super().__init__(...)  # Pass any args you want to pass to the super class, if applicable
    # Do whatever you want here
```

For future reference, "it doesn't seem to work anymore" is not very useful for people to find the problem. Add the actual error message to your post.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it, I didnt manage to catch any error upon that happening.
Thank you for clarifying

Comment: ```def __init__(self, player_1, player_2):
  super().__init__()
  self.player_1 = player_1
  self.player_2 = player_2
  print(f'This is player 1 {self.player_1}, player 2 {self.player_2}')```